# When someone intentionally or unintentionally makes you cross your writing

Tags: sentence-usage

Let's suppose you are writing a text and the person who is sitting beside you (no matter intentionally or unintentionally) nudges you and makes you cross what you were writing. How a native would normally indicate this happening?

> - He crossed my hand.
> - He made me cross my writing.

In order to make it more tangible I have uploaded an image.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

British English native here. The word I would use in that situation is to say that the person had ***[jogged](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/jog)*** me (the verb sense with the one-word summary "push"), or jogged my arm, or my hand. To clarify that this affected my writing, I would say that it ***messed up*** my writing.